# How to generate dynamically generated assets in Play 2.3 (so no compilation is triggered)?

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

How can you modify a play 2.3 project's build configuration to include assets that are generated dynamically by some task?

The goal is to achieve something similar to assets currently contained in the `app/assets` folder: take a file from somewhere, transfom it somehow (usually compiling it) and make it available as an asset under the /public directory.
I already tried adding a dependency to the `compile` task:

```
 compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) dependsOn Def.task {
    val file = //generate file

    IO.copyFile(file, baseDirectory.value / "public" / "foo.bar")
}
```

Although this solution works, it copies a file during compilation thus notifying play of changes an thus scheduling a new compilation, i.e. the application is reloaded on every http request!

Are there any other ways to add new dynamic assets without ending up in a vicious reload cycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should employ `resourceGenerators` that's the setting to manage *List of tasks that generate resources.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had actually also tried that and ended up in the same vicious cycle. As it turned out, it wasn't actually a vicious cycle after all, but a problem with JNotify causing multiple reloads on run.